# How to be a Stellar Anchor?

Tags: stellar-core, horizon, stellar.toml

There is currently not much info about this.

I want to provide the ability to exchange for XLM using the local fiat currency I am at.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read this article? [Become an Anchor](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/anchor/index.html)